# I'm having problem enabling Animation Nodes in blender 2.82

Tags: animation, node-editor, animation-nodes, error

I dont know what to do. Im pretty sure you will get the idea what is wrong by seeing this picture. I'm new doing animation in blender so any help will be apprreciated...[image: m]

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem when I upgraded recently.

I suspect you need to reinstall the vc_redist.x64 which has some windows features that AN uses.

Check out this link on the AN github, third item titled "Import Error: DLL load failed"

https://github.com/JacquesLucke/animation_nodes/issues/1240

After I reinstalled vc_redist, I went through the AN install process again and it worked normally.

HTH